# I can't view project in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

Hy,

I cannot load "next" page on Project screen in SonarQube in version 5.2 ...

1) I connect to in SonarQube application 
2) I click on "project" option in  "dashboard" menu
           The first page with 30 first project is loaded

[screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFzZw.jpg)

3) On bottom of the page i try to load the next page... but the login page appears and when a try to connect one more time with the same profile/password all connections fail with the following message "You are not authorized to access this page. Please log in with more privileges and try again". [screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdWOt.jpg)

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Can you check the server's log ? There's probably an error, could you send it ? If it's not the case, please check the console log of the navigator.

Comment: I deleted the dashboard and recreate it and the problem disappeared (Pb of sonar migration from 4.5.1 to 5.2 i hope). Thank you for your help.